# Regex to get substring outside quotes

Tags: ruby, regex

Is there a regex to replace all mentions of the substring in a string with another except those in quotation marks `"'`?

For example if the substring is "Hello" and the replaced string is "World":
`Hello Everybody "Hello" Everybody` should return `World Everybody "Hello" Everybody`

Sorry about the wording earlier, had a brainfart.

Comment: say whaaaat: `"hello " world"`

Comment: `removing the substring inside the quotes ... is not what I want` Then what is it that you want?

Comment: I just want to ignore the substring

Comment: How is that different from getting the string with the substring removed?

Comment: But which substring do you ignore if there are an odd number of quotes? Better yet, which substring do you ignore if there is more than one set of quotes?

Comment: I don't understand the example.  Shouldn't the expected string include "world", because there was an unquoted instance of it in the input string?  Also, the target string is "hello" (lowercase), but those words in the input string are "Hello" (capitalized).  Should case be ignored?

Comment: @WayneConrad Sorry about that, I'm not thinking straight today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use negative lookbehind and lookahead assertions for `"` or `'` like this:

```
(?<!["'])(Hello)(?!["'])
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/cR4zE6

Matches:

```
"Hello" world  //no match
Hello World  //matches "Hello"
```

**Edit:**

So in a replace situation:

Example string: `Hello Everybody "Hello" Everybody`

Replace with: `""` (nothing)

Output:

```
Everybody "Hello" Everybody
```

Comment: That won't match `"apple"Hello"world"` even though (arguably) it is apple and world in the quotes.

Comment: @DamienBlack, yes exactly, the OP does not want anything in quotes to match. So therefore, `"apple"Hello"world"` will not match.

Comment: but `hello` is _not_ in quotes there. It is "apple" and "world" that are in quotes. That also won't match `hello"world"`, here clearly "world" is in quotes, not hello.

Comment: It also succeeds on `"test hello world"`, which it shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookahead and negative lookbehind assertions. This works.

```
irb(main):050:0> testcases = ["hello world", "'hello world", "'hello' world", "hello' world", "hello\"world"]
=> ["hello world", "'hello world", "'hello' world", "hello' world", "hello\"world"]
irb(main):051:0> testcases.each { |i| puts /(?<!')(?<!")hello(?!")(?!')/.match(i) }
hello




=> ["hello world", "'hello world", "'hello' world", "hello' world", "hello\"world"]
```

Edit: Updated to include double quotes but can be extended for any character.

Comment: This does not work, it fails on `hello'world'` It also succeeds on `test hello world'`, which it shouldn't

Comment: The concept works, and I even explained the idea of negative lookahead , which is advance regexp concept. It can be updated to include additional character. Why the downvote?

Comment: there should be another quote on my above comment `'test hello world'`

Comment: It seems you are trolling, because your answer was not accepted, and I actually took the time to explain it.

Answer (score -1):

```
^([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*hello
```

This regex will match 'hello' only if there are an even number (including 0) of quotation characters before it (which indicates that it is not currently inside quotation marks).

To break it down:

- ^ :Start at the beginning of the string
- ( :Start the quotes group that can be repeated any number of times
- [^"]* :Match any number of non-quote characters, for arbitrary text before quotes
- " :Match the opening quote
- [^"]* :Match any number of non-quote characters (this is the stuff in the quotes)
- " :Match the closing quote
- )* :End the quotes group and repeat it any number of time including 0
- [^"]* :match any additional non-quote characters, for arbitrary text before your word
- hello :your word

Unlike other answers here, this will succeed on the following cases:

```
"apple"hello"world"
```

Because `apple` and `world` are in quotes, not hello.

And this will fail on

```
"apple hello world"
```

Because hello is still in quotes